# Determining what coordinates I click on VNC

Tags: vnc, vncserver

Is there an easy way to determine the coordinates I'm hitting (server-side) with VNC or a VNC viewer? Or a logging feature server-side that'll spit out what coordinates I'm clicking?

A VNC viewer that keeps track of my cursor position (relative to the VNC window, at least) would work too.